# Silverstripe - Is it possible to use a variable in an include statement?

Tags: templates, variables, include, silverstripe

I am using the silverstripe templating and I want to loop through the child pages of the current page and dynamically input the template name in the 'include' control depending on that child's page type.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    <div id="tertiary-content">                   
        <% if $Children %>
            <% loop $Children %>
                <% include $ClassName %>
            <% end_loop %>
        <% end_if %>
    </div>
```

(I have ss files in my templates/Includes directory that relate to the $ClassName variable)

Here's the error I get:

**Error was: Unknown open block "loop" encountered. Perhaps you missed the closing tag or have mis-spelled it?**

I found this article from a silverstripe forum which makes me think it should work:
http://www.silverstripe.org/archive/show/1023

Is it actually possible to have a variable in an include control?

Comment: I don't know for Silverstripe but you can definitely use a variable as a include in php. includes are usually withing '' though.

Comment: Silverstripe uses its own templating system and this is actually the template (.ss file) which doesn't use php, I also tried putting the $ClassName variable in {} but that gave me the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some test and could not get `<% include $ClassName %>` to work. But you could work around it with something like:

```
<% if $ClassName = 'SomeClass' %>
    <% include SomeClass %> 
<% else_if $ClassName = 'SomeOtherClass' %>
    <% include SomeOtherClass %>
<% else %>
    <% include DefaultClass %>
<% end_if %>
```

Not as pretty, but does the job.

Comment: This is how I am solving the issue currently, I was hoping to make it more dynamic so if we wanted to add another page type in the future, we wouldn't have to alter this code to account for it. This definitely is one way to solve it, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You could write a function in your Page class that loads a ss template based on the current class name. In your Page.php file.

```
class Page extends SiteTree {

/**
 * Returns a template based on the current ClassName
 * @return {mixed} template to be rendered
 **/
public function getIncludeTemplate(){
    return $this->renderWith($this->ClassName);
}

}
```

and then in your Template

```
<div id="tertiary-content">                   
    <% if $Children %>
        <% loop $Children %>
            $IncludeTemplate
        <% end_loop %>
    <% end_if %>
</div>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure renderWith() is called when the page is loaded and I am using jquery to load the child content. Marking up because this is a good solution if I wasn't hide/showing the content with jquery

Comment: If you are using jQuery to load the child content, then I assume you're loading the content via AJAX? If so, then your controller method that returns the JSON/HTML/etc can make this test for child object type, and return the appropriate output.

Answer (score 5):

You could call `renderWith` directly from the template, e.g.:

```
<div id="tertiary-content">                   
    <% if $Children %>
        <% loop $Children %>
            $renderWith($ClassName)
        <% end_loop %>
    <% end_if %>
</div>
```